# No se como anular el prevent default en JS

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo mi portafolio pero me encontré con un problema al autenticar mi formulario y no se como solucionarlo, el formulario va a ser enviado por netlify, el problema es que se aplica el prevent default aunque todo este correcto, ayer me funcionaba el form.submit(); y si se enviaba el formulario, pero desde que le puse verificacion a el nombre y mensaje me dejo de funcionar y en la consola me aparece "form is not defined at HTMLButtonElement" pero mi boton de enviar tiene el type submit, si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradeceria mucho, de antemano gracias

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    //Carga el efecto de typed
    libreriaTyped();
    //Validar todo
    validarTodo();
    //Validar nombre
    validarNombre();
    //Validar mensaje
    validarMensaje();
})

function libreriaTyped() {
    const typed = new Typed('.typed', {
        strings: [
        '<i class="habilidad">JavaScript</i>',
        '<i class="habilidad">SASS</i>',
        '<i class="habilidad">CSS</i>',
        '<i class="habilidad">HTML</i>'
                ],
        typeSpeed: 100,
        startDelay: 500,
        backSpeed: 100,
        loop: true,
        contentType: 'html',
    });
}

function prevenirDefault() {
    const enviar = document.querySelector('.Enviar')
    enviar.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        validarNombre();
        validarMensaje();
    })
}

function submit() {
    const enviar = document.querySelector('.Enviar')
    enviar.addEventListener('click', e => {
       form.submit();
    })
}



function validarTodo() {
    const formulario = document.querySelector('.contenedor-formulario')

    const enviar = document.querySelector('.Enviar')

    const alertaAlgo = document.querySelector('.alerta-nombre')
    
    enviar.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if (document.getElementsByName("Nombre")[0].value < 4  || document.getElementsByName("E-mail")[0].value == "" || document.getElementsByName("mensaje")[0].value == "")
        {
            const alertaPrevia = document.querySelector('.alerta')
            if (alertaPrevia) {
                alertaPrevia.remove();
            }


            const alerta = document.createElement('P')
            alerta.classList.add('alerta')
            alerta.textContent = 'Formulario invalido, llene los datos correctamente'
            formulario.appendChild(alerta)
            setTimeout(() => {
                alerta.remove();
            }, 3000);
            
            
            
            e.preventDefault()
        }  else {
            form.submit();
        }
    });   
}

function validarNombre() {
    const nombre = document.querySelector('#Nombre')
    const formulario = document.querySelector('.contenedor-formulario')

    nombre.addEventListener('input', e => {
        const contenidoNombre = e.target.value;
        if ( contenidoNombre.length < 3 || contenidoNombre.length > 12) {
            alertaPrevia = document.querySelector('.alerta-nombre')
            if (alertaPrevia) {
                alertaPrevia.remove();
            }

            const alerta = document.createElement('P')
            alerta.classList.add('alerta-nombre')
            alerta.textContent = 'Nombre invalido, completelo correctamente'
            formulario.appendChild(alerta)
            

            prevenirDefault();
            
        } else  {
            alertaPrevia = document.querySelector('.alerta-nombre')
            if (alertaPrevia) {
                alertaPrevia.remove();
            }
            validarTodo();
        }
    })
}

function validarMensaje() {
    const mensaje = document.querySelector('#Mensaje')
    const formulario = document.querySelector('.contenedor-formulario')
    mensaje.addEventListener('input', e => {
        const contenidoMensaje = e.target.value;
        if (contenidoMensaje.length < 10) {
            const alertaPrevia = document.querySelector('.alerta-mensaje')
            if (alertaPrevia) {
                alertaPrevia.remove();
            } 
                

            const alertaMensaje = document.createElement('P')
            alertaMensaje.classList.add('alerta-mensaje')
            alertaMensaje.textContent = 'Mensaje demasiado corto'

            //Añadir al html
            formulario.appendChild(alertaMensaje)
            prevenirDefault();
        } else {
            const alertaPrevia = document.querySelector('.alerta-mensaje')
            if (alertaPrevia) {
                alertaPrevia.remove();
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: No crees que puede haber confusión al declarar la función con el mismo nombre del método `preventDefault`?? Y no solo con ese sino con todos los demás

Comment: ya cambie el nombre de la funcion y sigue igual :(

Comment: Creo que tu error esta en que: en tu función tienes un parámetro que no estas usando con el nombre `e` y ademas de esto, ese es el nombre que le das a el evento en el **listener** `enviar.addEventListener('click', e => { ... }`

Comment: Esto podría causar un mala referencia, llamando así a una función `preventDefault()` que no existe de un parametro vació. No se si me explico bien disculpa jaja

Comment: ¿Por cierto, `.Enviar` es el único elemento que tienes con ese **Class Name** en tu documento?

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, si, .enviar es la unica clase que tengo con ese nombre, y ya quite el e en la funcion prevenirDefault, pero en la consola me sigue saltando       "Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement"

Comment: ehhmm una pregunta ¿Donde defines `form`? Veo que lo usas `form.submit();` pero no veo su definición

Comment: lo de `form` lo vi en una pagina en donde vi como autenticar formularios, supongo que lo defino en el html en `Type="Form"`

Comment: probe a usar `const form =`  y con `querySelector ` seleccione el boton, pero tampoco me dejo

Comment: Nono, `form` deberia ser una referencia a tu formulario, ejemplo `form = document.querySelector('#mi-formulario')`. Observa [esto](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp)

Comment: el método `submit()` es un método que tienen todos los formularios web, que es el equivalente a hacer **click** sobre el `<input type="submit">`, pero *programaticamente*

Comment: listo, lo logre, muchisimas gracias, lo que tenia que hacer era  `document.getElementById("formularioDeContacto").submit();`, es decir seleccionar el formulario y no solo el boton, a parte de seleccionar el formulario con `document.getElementById`, de verdad muchas gracias, estaba demasiado frustrado, muchisimas gracias. un saludo.

Comment: Perfecto..!! con gusto :)